# Needed requirements for an estimated traffic of 3000 clicks per week

Tags: performance, bandwidth, memory

I've an estimated traffic of 3000 clicks per week. So about 12000 per month.

Is a VPS with 256MB RAM and 150GB bandwidth enough for such website ?

If no, how do you suggest to upgrade ?

thanks

Update: It is a Drupal-based website, but without videos, just images and e-commerce

Comment: It depends - if every click downloads a 4Gb video file, then probably not.

What's the average size per click? Average response time? Average memory footprint?

Comment: @symcbean Ok, i've updated my question. No video. The memory footprint is given by Drupal (is this a good answer ?) I don't understand why you ask me the response time (isn't given by server performances ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3000 clicks per week should be no problem (since you aren't trying something like BlueGene via HTTP arent you - since this would probably be to much) as you can see by using quite simple mathematics:

```
3000 clicks per week / 7 / 24 = 17 clicks per hour
```

If you serve a normal webapplication this should be fine.

So based on your estimated clicks let's check bandwith:

```
150GB BW per Month = 153600 MB per Month / 12000 Clicks = 12.8 MB per Click
```

Comment: good answer with nice back of the enveloppe calculations

Comment: Just a caution that web traffic tends to be "bursty".  You'll need to look at traffic for your site to figure how often and how high these bursts can get.  For example, you may see bursts of 5x your average load on weekdays just before noon.  To prevent the "fail wale" you'll need to spec out your server for these worst case scenarios and buffer in a bit more for the slash-dot affect if it's a public site. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

For a simple website without videos and big files on your server, that would be more than enough.